# How do you implement Ionic2 Virtual Scroll when you have an array of objects that have an array of objects?

Tags: html, arrays, angular, ionic2

Using Ionic2/Angular2 I want to use Virtual scroll to make manageable a long list of contacts in contact invite. I've tried replacing both of my *ngFor with [virtualScroll].

The array to map:

```
var groupedContacts = [contactObject...];
var contactObject = {letter: "a", contacts: [singleContactObject...]};
//scores or even hundreds of contacts per letter
var singleContactObject = {name: "someName", number: "somePhone"};
```

Original HTML

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item-group class="invite-sheet" *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">
   <ion-item-divider class="header-letter">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts">
      <ion-row align-items-center>
         <ion-col width-40>
            <h4 text-wrap class="name-invite">{{contact.name}}</h4>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-35>
            <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-25>
            <button class="inner-invite" (click)="invite(contact)">Invite</button>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

HTML attempt 1:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item-group [virtualScroll] = "groupedContacts">
   <ion-item-divider *virtualHeader="let group">
            {{group.letter}}
   </ion-item-divider>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let contact of group.contacts">
      <ion-row align-items-center>
         <ion-col width-40>
            <h4 text-wrap class="name-invite">{{contact.name}}</h4>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-35>
            <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-25>
            <button class="inner-invite" (click)="invite(contact)">Invite</button>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

HTML attempt 2:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item-group [virtualScroll] = "groupedContacts">
   <ion-item-divider *virtualHeader="let group">
            {{group.letter}}
   </ion-item-divider>
   <ion-item-group [virtualScroll]="contacts">
      <ion-row align-items-center>
         <ion-col width-40 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <h4 text-wrap class="name-invite">{{contact.name}}</h4>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-35 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-25 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <button class="inner-invite" (click)="invite(contact)">Invite</button>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

HTML attempt 3:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-item-group class="invite-sheet" *ngFor="let group of groupedContacts">
   <ion-item-divider class="header-letter">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
   <ion-item-group [virtualScroll]="group.contacts">
      <ion-row align-items-center>
         <ion-col width-40 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <h4 text-wrap class="name-invite">{{contact.name}}</h4>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-35 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col width-25 *virtualItem="let contact">
            <button class="inner-invite" (click)="invite(contact)">Invite</button>
         </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
   </ion-item>
</ion-item-group>
</ion-content>
```

No of the attempts produced results so I must fundamentally misunderstand something.

UPDATE:
Here is what I came up with after seeing @wannadream recommendation. I get a blank screen:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-list [virtualScroll]="groupedContacts" approxItemHeight="50px">
   <ion-item *virtualItem="#group">
     <ion-item-divider class="header-letter">{{group.letter}}</ion-item-divider>
      <ion-list [virtualScroll]="group.contacts" approxItemHeight="50px">
        <ion-item *virtualItem="#contact">
          <ion-col width-40>
            <h4 text-wrap class="name-invite">{{contact.name}}</h4>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-35>
            <p>{{contact.number}}</p>
          </ion-col>
          <ion-col width-25>
            <button class="inner-invite" (click)="invite(contact)">Invite</button>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can I at least get a reason why I got minus points? Seriously, what is wrong with this. I put lots of example code for things I've tried etc.!

Comment: Just ignore it. Not all of the people have the right attitude. Let's focus on your question.

Comment: Where is <ion-list>? Maybe you can take a look at this tutorial: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/04/25/an-example-of-virtualscroll-and-infinite-scroll-in-ionic-2

Comment: @wannadream; Is there no example of a virtual scroll working with a second virtual scroll or ngFor? That is my situation here and so far I've been unable to get it to work in this situation.

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: @rashadb did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @shaneparsons, I abandoned virtual scroll and went with infinite scroll. If I remember correctly (it's been several months now), my issues had nothing to do with virtual/infinite scroll but rather that you can't nest ion-item-group and/or ion-list.